# Regex match 4 to 60 characters, space, single quote and exclude trailing spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match 4 to 60 characters, space, single quote, and exclude trailing spaces.

Cases:

1. "aa aa" - match
2. "tes'" - match
3. "not                          " - not match
4. "asdpijfaousdhfaoijsdgohasd' asdfa adsfads" - match

I need to exclude trailing spaces from this regex

`^[\\w\'\ ]{4,60}$`

`[ \t]+$` - don't know how to add this to this regex

Comment: Try `^(?=[\w' \t]{4,60}$)[\w']+(?:[ \t][\w']+)*$` https://regex101.com/r/NKBWR7/1

Comment: What is a “character”?

Comment: @Thefourthbird it doesn't match at all if there are trailing spaces

Comment: @jonatjano I updated it with the wrong pattern, now it is back to the right one.

Comment: @Thefourthbird still got the problem, if you add a trailing space to a selection, it doesn't select anymore

Comment: @Thefourthbird it works fine. add the answer and I will accept, thanks

Comment: @jonatjano It is stated in the question that it should not `and exclude trailing spaces`

Comment: @Thefourthbird my bad then, I read it as it should still match but stop the match before the first trailing space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use a pattern where the repeating parts starts with either a space or tab. At the start of the pattern, you could assert a length of 4 - 60 chars using a positive lookahead.

```
^(?=[\w' \t]{4,60}$)[\w']+(?:[ \t][\w']+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NKBWR7/1)

```js
const pattern = /^(?=[\w' \t]{4,60}$)[\w']+(?:[ \t][\w']+)*$/;
[
  "aa aa",
  "tes'",
  "not ",
  "asdpijfaousdhfaoijsdgohasd' asdfa adsfads"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(`${s} --> ${pattern.test(s)}`)
)
```